# error de http 403 forbidden youtube api v3 Forbbiden

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, http-status-code-403

When performed Retrieve my  I get the following error:

Language C #

> "Code": 403,         
>     "Message": "Forbidden"

Example code:

```
 request.Service.QueryClientLoginToken ();
 Uri urlVideo = new Uri (String.Format ("googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={0}&key={1}&part=snippet" videoId, hipoConfig.clave_api)); 
 Video videoExistente = request.Retrieve <video> (urlVideo);
 log.escribirInfoLog ("Information: Video" + videoExistente.VideoId + "is removed from YouTube to be replaced"); 
 request.Delete (videoExistente);
```

Comment: Example code:

  request.Service.QueryClientLoginToken ();
Uri urlVideo = new Uri(String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={0}&key={1}&part=snippet" videoId, hipoConfig.clave_api));
 
Video videoExistente = request.Retrieve <video> (urlVideo);

 log.escribirInfoLog ("Information: Video" + videoExistente.VideoId + "is removed from YouTube to be replaced");

 request.Delete (videoExistente);

Comment: Example code:
  request.Service.QueryClientLoginToken ();

     Uri urlVideo = new Uri (String.Format ("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={0}&key={1}&part=snippet" videoId, hipoConfig.clave_api));                  
   Video videoExistente = request.Retrieve <video> (urlVideo);
     log.escribirInfoLog ("Information: Video" + videoExistente.VideoId + "is removed from YouTube to be replaced");
 request.Delete (videoExistente);